# About Anchor Tag

Tags: html, c#-4.0

I want to hide my anchor tag which looks as follows:
Inventory

Now on Boolean condition on code behind i want to change it's visibility dynamically.
Help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have ANY code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned code behind. I am assuming it is ASP.NET Webforms

1. Add an id and runat="server" tag to the anchortag
2. In you page load access the control using the id and set `.Visible` property based on your condition